# how to join 4 images to one image button (android)

Tags: android, imagebutton

Hello I need to join 4 separate images into one `ImageButton`

I want to attach the images Which should look like that on one image button Thanks for you help.
How can I do it ?

```
Img1 on top
Img2  img3 at the middle
Img4 at bottom
```

Like a pyramid

Comment: did you try ? and show image that you want

Comment: you will have to use canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice article on merging 2 pictures.

Take a look, and then try to connect 4 of them

http://android-er.blogspot.dk/2013/08/merge-two-image-overlap-with-alpha.html

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Button:

```
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/btn_back"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bd_logo"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/btn_close"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/btn_ok"/>
```

**Left Img:**

```
yourButtonId.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.smiley, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: He wants img2 and img3 in middle. And you can not set them with this xml

Comment: Can I change the top/left/right/down from Java code ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't have to use an `imageButton` for that. You can create a new `LinearLayout`, and assign a `setOnClickListener` method to that `LinearLayout`. So that it behaves like a button and you can locate as many images the way you wanted. For example;

The XML code for `LinearLayout`;

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/imagebutton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Declaration in your Activity;

```
LinearLayout imageButton = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton);
```

Handling click events;

```
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //TODO

        }
    });
```

Comment: Your idea is very cool but the problem this is a board game, and "computer" has to iterate the matrix of image button. Can I iterate with for loop on those layout ?